# joining two subtables in excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to make a join from 2 sub tables created by query 1 and 2 I tried many different kinds of combinations but I keep getting errors, how can I properly do that ? the code below says I do not have support for expression join.

```
Sub test()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

StrFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & StrFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"


Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon
strsql = "(SELECT tab.Categoria AS cat1, sum(tab.Vo) AS somavo FROM [Fluxo de caixa$A1:P2638] tab GROUP BY tab.Categoria)"
strsql2 = "(SELECT tab2.Categoria AS cat2, sum(tab2.Vpago) AS somapg FROM [Fluxo de caixa$A1:P2638] tab2 GROUP BY tab2.Categoria)"

strsql3 = "SELECT cat1, cat2, somavo, somapg FROM " & strsql & " LEFT JOIN " & strsql2 & " ON cat1=cat2"

rs.Open strsql3, cn
If (rs.EOF) And (rs.BOF) Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Sheets("aux").Range("a1:zz1048576").ClearContents
    Sheets("aux").Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset rs
End If
rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: If these are coming from sheets why not just use data > tools > merge queries? Having added source ranges as table via data > tools > from table/range? You can self-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked

```
strsql = "(SELECT tab1.Categoria AS cat1, sum(tab1.Vo) AS somavo FROM [Fluxo de caixa$A1:P2638] tab1 GROUP BY tab1.Categoria) otab1"
strsql2 = "(SELECT tab2.Categoria AS cat2, sum(tab2.Vpago) AS somapg FROM [Fluxo de caixa$A1:P2638] tab2 GROUP BY tab2.Categoria) otab2"

strsql3 = "SELECT * FROM " & strsql & " LEFT OUTER JOIN " & strsql2 & " ON otab1.cat1=otab2.cat2"
```